# How to get OSX ttf fonts into Linux

Tags: linux, osx-snow-leopard, fonts, truetype-fonts

There are some fonts in OSX I want to use into Linux. Do I just have to copy them into some directory? How can I transfer fonts from OSX into Linux?

Comment: ​Which Linux​?​

Comment: if the fonts are of ttf format you can save them in the "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/" folder.

Comment: Then do I have to just restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can legally use them, then create a `~/.fonts` directory, copy the fonts into it, and run `fc-cache ~/.fonts"`.  You may also have to create a `~/.fonts.conf`, although on most systems the system-wide `fonts.conf` already includes `~/.fonts`; see `man fonts.conf` for details.)  You will probably have to restart any running programs to get them to see the new fonts, as programs usually read the font directory cache once and save it in memory.

I have occasionally had fonts not work on Linux, probably because they don't quite follow the spec (the FreeType library rejects some things that Windows and OS X allow).  There are programs out there that can attempt to fix such fonts; try Google.  (Last time I looked was over a year ago.)

(Edit:  someone else pointed you to the system-wide folder.  You'll need to run `sudo fc-cache` in that case.)

Comment: I've not had to run `fc-cache` on my system; it depends entirely on which distro, version, and DE you run.